# Running a perl script from proxy in Apache xampp

Tags: apache, perl, proxy, xampp

I'm using Windows 10 OS. I have used

```html
<VirtualHost *:9001>
  ProxyRequests On
  <Proxy>
    Order deny,allow Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/App/ ProxyPassReverse /
  http://localhost:8080/App/
</VirtualHost>
```

for doing the proxy settings. I have created a virtual host.

Can anyone suggest me how to run a Perl script from here by giving the document root and call the Perl script from proxy settings?